# Android Google GCM - Is it possible to display alert when device is in sleep mode with security enabled?

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-cloud-messaging

We use Google Cloud Messaging to receive message on Android devices. Is it possible to display GCM message on device if device is in sleep mode with security enabled. (Using API > 2.3....4.0).

Device will be secured by either pattern or face recognition. We want the GCM message to display regardless of the state of the device. Ideally we want the device to stay locked but also show the message, if not possible, we can settle for unlock device automatically and wake up to show the message.

There is an app that displays the message from GCM on the device. So, my question boils down to if an app is allowed to display a message on a device that is locked using pattern security for example.

Feedback is much appreciated.

**I have tried "FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED" since keygaurdmanager is deprecated but it doesn't work for some reason. Screen lights up but security pattern stays on.**

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question to add a few more sentences about what you think "display GCM message" means, as what the rest of us will think of as a "GCM message" has no UI.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is an app that does the job of displaying. So, the developer tells me that the app is not able to wake up the device from sleep mode and unlock it if it is locked using something like pattern lock.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want. If not please ignore my answer.

First add these permissions to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

In my app, I showed the user the messages by an activity, then in `onCreate()`, I used these codes:

```
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.view.WindowManager;

// ...

private KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock mKeyguardLock;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ...

    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    mKeyguardLock = km.newKeyguardLock(ClassName);
    mKeyguardLock.disableKeyguard();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                    | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, ClassName);
    wl.acquire();

    getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
}// onCreate()
```

Make sure to re-enable keyguard in `onDestroy()`:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mKeyguardLock.reenableKeyguard();
}// onDestroy()
```

I just copied those codes from a blog post (unfortunately I can't remember where it is). And it worked (with `minSdkVersion` = 7, tested on real devices 2.x, on emulators <= ICS). If you could, please try and let me know if it'd work.

---

*Edit*

I'm not sure, it seems that is this [blog post](http://philonandroid.blogspot.cz/2009_10_01_archive.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot Lai, but Keyguard seems to have been deprecated. Alternative is FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I didn't notice that  :-(